# multiple column with muptiple rows data to a single row & for the non duplicated data need concadination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[Currently data is like below:-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr8fk.png)

[image]

```
SQL Query:-
declare @t table
(
    Id int,
    ReportedDate DATE,
    [Name] varchar(10)
)
insert into @t

select 1,'2016-01-01','ab' union all
select 2,'2016-01-01','a' union all
select 1,'2016-01-20','hha' union all
select 2,'2016-01-20','jnsjja' union all
select 1,'2016-01-01','jsjb' union all
select 2,'2016-01-01','sjjjwb' union all
select 1,'2016-01-20','bjd' union all
select 2,'2016-01-20','bwjw'

select * from @t order by id, ReportedDate
```

Expected Result:-

[image]

It's working in case we have only 2 columns, one is Id & other one is anything. But for mutiple column I am unable

Comment: Looks like this is your answer...[Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: As I mentioned It's working in case we have only 2 columns, but for mutiple columns I am unable. For 2 columns I have query                                select t.Id,

(
    select  [Name] + ',' from @t where Id = t.Id for XML path('')
)
from (select Id from @t )t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are countless examples for this, however, since you have a nicely structured question which is easy to copy and paste....

```
Select A.ID 
      ,A.ReportedDate
      ,Name  = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' +Name From @t Where ID=A.ID and ReportedDate=A.ReportedDate For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From (Select Distinct ID,ReportedDate From @t ) A
```

Returns

```
ID  ReportedDate    Name
1   2016-01-01      ab,jsjb
1   2016-01-20      bjd,hha
2   2016-01-01      a,sjjjwb
2   2016-01-20      bwjw,jnsjja
```